# Polymer neon-animated pages: no transition animation played

Tags: javascript, polymer, node-webkit

I'm trying to build an application using node-webkit and Polymer 1.0.

One part of it - pageable welcome screens to give a short overview of app's features to user.

I'm using neon-animated pages for that. The page-switching works perfectly. But no animations are played.

I'd be very happy if anyone could give me at least the direction where my problem could be - I'm out of ideas. See the code below.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animation.html">

<link rel="import" href="./domComponents/switchableAnimatedPages.html">
<link rel="import" href="./components/welcome/welcomeScreen.html">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bower_components/signalr/jquery.signalR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    global.$ = $;
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>

<welcome-screen></welcome-screen>
<script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**welcomeScreen.html**

```
<dom-module id="welcome-screen">

<style>
    :host {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<template>
    <switchable-animated-pages>
        <neon-animatable>1</neon-animatable>
        <neon-animatable>2</neon-animatable>
    </switchable-animated-pages>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'welcome-screen'
    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

**switchableAnimatedPages.html**

```
<dom-module id="switchable-animated-pages">

<style>
    :host {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #pages {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #00bcd6;
    }

    #switcher {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
    }
</style>

<template>
    <neon-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{selectedPage}}"
        entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
        <content></content>
    </neon-animated-pages>
    <div id="switcher" on-click="switchPage"></div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({

        is: 'switchable-animated-pages',

        properties: {
            selectedPage: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0,
                notify: true
            }
        },

        switchPage: function() {
            this.selectedPage = this.selectedPage ? 0 : 1;
        }

    });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. Which version of `neon-animation` are you using? There is a bug in version 2.1.1 of the web animations polyfill that prevented animations from running, and [version 1.0.5](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/releases/tag/v1.0.5) of `neon-animation` pins the polyfill to a working version.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had 1.0.0 version of neon animation. Thank you very much